# Why is it not the case that f(t, x(t)) = f(t)?

Tags: functions, time-series

What is the difference between:
$f(t)$
and,
$f(x(t), t)$

Can I write any function $f(x(t), t)$ as $f(t)$?
Why or why not?

Explanations in detail with supporting examples going from simple to complicated would be very helpful.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use the same letter to denote the two functions.  One is a function of two variables, the other a function of one variable.

Comment: @lulu What I mean is can a function f which is a function of t and x (which itself is a function of t) be written only using t? I say this as x itself can be written as a function of t. So I can replace that in the expressions.

Comment: Take an example.  Suppose $f(x,y)=x^2y+x$.  Now suppose that $x,y$ are functions of $t$.  Let's say $x(t)=t^2$ and $y(t)=t+1$.  Then we get a function of one variable, $t$, as $F(t)=f(x(t),y(t))=t^4\times (t+1)+t^2=t^5+t^4+t^2$.  That function is, of course, derived from $f$, but I would not call it $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $f(x(t),t)$ entails $f$ is a function of **two** variables, while writing $f(t)$ entails it is a function of one variable, so you can never write such an equality. However, it is true that a function of the form $f(x(t),t)$ is of the form $g(t)$, where $g$ is simply defined by $t \mapsto f(x(t), t)$.

Comment: Yes, +1. With careful definitions of the notation, one can write this function as $g = f\circ (x\times \operatorname{id})$.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, $y=f(t)$ is a function of 1 "free" variable which will "convert" or "map" the given "$t$" to the matching "$y$" , whereas $y=f(x,t)$ is a function of 2 "free" variables.

It may turn out that when we have $y=f(x,t)$ , in some case , $x$ & $t$ may have constraints which make it true that $x=X(t)$ , then we may write $y=f(x,t)=f(X(t),t)$ & see that we have only 1 "free" variable $t$ due to that constraint.

We should now introduce (or make) a new function to write this new condition $y=f(x,t)=f(X(t),t)=F(t)$ where $f$ & $F$ are not same.

It is a (BAD) Practice to sometimes write $f(t)$ (Eg to make it convenient & less verbose on a black board) where rigorous analysis states that we should use $F(t)$ but when there is no ambiguity, we can sometimes get away with this sloppy abuse of notation.

Better avoid this BAD Practice & introduce a new function which is more rigorous & will avoid unnecessary ambiguity & confusion.

OP is asking for Examples, hence consider this :

$z=f(x,y)=|x \cdot y|$ where :
$x,y,z$ are real numbers ,
$x,y$ are Co-Ordinates of Points on a Plane ,
$z$ is the area of the rectangle between the Point $(x,y)$ & the Origin $(0,0)$ with horizontal & vertical sides.

Let us consider only Squares, that is , we want $y=Y(x)=x$
Then we get $z=f(x,Y(x))=|x \cdot Y(x)|=|x \cdot x|=x^2$
We should write it like $z=F(x)=x^2$
We can give a meaning to $F(x)$ that this gives the area of a Square with a side between the Origin & a Point on the x-axis

Here, we see that $f$ was using Points on a Plane while $F$ is using Points on a line.

It is convenient & wrong to write $z=f(x)=x^2$, but it is abuse of notation & will be confusing when overdone. We must be a little verbose to write or introduce the new function correctly.